# I can not save a layer in geoserver after canceling the action

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I'm canceling an action of insert layer in openlayers doing this(and work ok):

```
wfs.eraseFeatures([e.feature]);
e.feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
saveStrategy.save();
$('#dlglogradouro').dialog('close');
```

But after, im trying to save another layer but not work more, and dont give any error, somebody could help me? (above code work if im not cancel before)

```
e.feature.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;
saveStrategy.save();
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see some more code before we can help, what happens when you hit cancel, where does the program go next?

Answer (score 0):

Yes has more code, but I thought that part of the code was wrong and I was right.

This is the problem:

```
wfs.eraseFeatures([e.feature]);
e.feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
saveStrategy.save();
$('#dlglogradouro').dialog('close');
```

change for:

```
wfs.destroyFeatures([e.feature]);
$('#dlglogradouro').dialog('close');
```

and all works!